# Global variables/ Classes

Tags: python

I need to pass a value created within a class method to a function, or procedure or def or whatever it is called, in the 'main program'

```
global myValue

class CalcFrame(object):
        def clearFunc(self):
                myValue = 12

def getUrl():
        print myValue
```

This was my idea, obviously it does not work:

I do that code, then I create an object

```
x = CalcFrame()
```

call the method which should set the global

```
x.clearFunc()
```

then call the function which should print it

```
getUrl()
```

get the error

> NameError: global name 'myValue' is not defined

Comment: That's not how the global keyword works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not how the `global` keyword is used.

It should be used this way instead

```
myValue = None

class CalcFrame(object):
    def clearFunc(self):
            global myValue
            myValue = 12
```

In a nutshell, `global` allows a function to **modify** a variable that **exists** in the global scope. See here for more info: https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python